# How to Add Edit and Delete in vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I want to add, delete, edit data through form by submitting it in vuex and run it via id. I tried many ways but still can't add, edit, please help me to edit my code. Thank you for the elders who came through to help me.

index.js - vuex file

```
import { createStore } from "vuex";

export default createStore({
  state: {
    data: [
      {
        id: 1,
        firstname: "test",
        lastname: "test",
        email: "test@gmail.com",
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        firstname: "hhh",
        lastname: "tttt",
        email: "ttt@gmail.com",
      }
    ],
  },
  getters: {
    allData: (state) => state.data
  },
  mutations: {
    NEW_DATA(state, newdata) {
      state.data.push(newdata);
    }, 
  },
  actions: {
    addNewUser({commit}, newdata) {
      console.log("NEW_DATA", newdata);
      commit("NEW_DATA", newdata);
    },
  },
  modules: {},
});
```

newData.vue - Add Data file

```
<template>
  <!-- Form [New Data] -->
  <div id="NewData" class="modal">
    <form class="modal-content animate" @submit.prevent="addUser()">
      <!-- button (X) -->
      <div>
        <button
          @click="close_NewData"
          class="close bt-cloae"
          title="Close Modal"
          type="reset"
        >
          <i class="bi bi-x-circle-fill"></i>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="imgcontainer">
        <h2>กรอกข้อมูล</h2>
      </div>

      <!-- input -->
      <div class="container">
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="floatingInput"
            placeholder="Firstname"
            v-model="Firstname"
            required
          />
          <label for="floatingInput">Firstname</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="floatingInput"
            placeholder="Lastname"
            v-model="Lastname"
            required
          />
          <label for="floatingInput">Lastname</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
          <input
            type="email"
            class="form-control"
            id="floatingInput"
            placeholder="Lastname"
            v-model="Email"
            required
          />
          <label for="floatingInput">Email</label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- button in form -->
      <div class="container">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success buttons">Add Data</button>
        <button
          type="reset"
          @click="close_NewData"
          class="btn btn-danger buttons"
        >
          Cancel
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex';
export default {
  computed:{
    ...mapGetters(["allData"])
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('addNewUser'),
    addUser() {
      var newUser = {
        firstname: this.Firstname,
        lastname: this.Lastname,
        email: this.Email,
      };
      this.$store.dispatch("addNewUser", newUser);      
      this.Firstname = this.Lastname = this.Email = "";
      document.getElementById("NewData").style.display = "none";
    },
    close_NewData() {
      document.getElementById("NewData").style.display = "none";
    },
    open_NewData() {
      document.getElementById("NewData").style.display = "block";
    },

  },
};
</script>

<style>
/* Css NewData */
form {
  margin: 2rem auto;
  border-radius: 12px;
  max-width: 50rem;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #fff;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

/* Extra styles for the cancel button */
.cancelbtn {
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  background-color: #f44336;
}

/* Center the image and position the close button */
.imgcontainer {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
  position: relative;
}

img.avatar {
  width: 30%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.container {
  padding: 16px;
}

span.psw {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
  padding-top: 60px;
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 5% auto 15% auto; /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and centered */
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button (x) */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 10px;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.bt-cloae {
  border: none;
}
.buttons {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
table {
  text-align: center;
}

/* Add Zoom Animation */
.animate {
  -webkit-animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
  animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatezoom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes animatezoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

/* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  span.psw {
    display: block;
    float: none;
  }
  .cancelbtn {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
</style>
```

editData.vue - Edit Data file

```
<template>
  <!-- Form [Edit Data] -->
  <div id="EditData" class="modal">
    <form class="modal-content animate" @submit.prevent="addUser()">
      <!-- button (X) -->
      <div>
        <button
          @click="close_EditData"
          class="close bt-cloae"
          title="Close Modal"
          type="reset"
        >
          <i class="bi bi-x-circle-fill"></i>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="imgcontainer">
        <h2>แก้ไขข้อมูล</h2>
      </div>

      <!-- input -->
      <div class="container">
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="floatingInput"
            placeholder="Firstname"
            v-model="Firstname"
            required
          />
          <label for="floatingInput">Firstname</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="floatingInput"
            placeholder="Lastname"
            v-model="Lastname"
            required
          />
          <label for="floatingInput">Lastname</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
          <input
            type="email"
            class="form-control"
            id="floatingInput"
            placeholder="Lastname"
            v-model="Email"
            required
          />
          <label for="floatingInput">Email</label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- button in form -->
      <div class="container">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success buttons">Add Data</button>
        <button
          type="reset"
          @click="close_EditData"
          class="btn btn-danger buttons"
        >
          Cancel
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    addUser() {
      var newUser = {
        firstname: this.Firstname,
        lastname: this.Lastname,
        email: this.Email,
      };
      this.$store.dispatch("addNewUser", newUser);
      this.Firstname = this.Lastname = this.Email = "";
      document.getElementById("NewData").style.display = "none";
    },
    close_EditData() {
      document.getElementById("EditData").style.display = "none";
    },
    open_EditData() {
      document.getElementById("EditData").style.display = "block";
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
/* Css NewData */
form {
  margin: 2rem auto;
  border-radius: 12px;
  max-width: 50rem;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #fff;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

/* Extra styles for the cancel button */
.cancelbtn {
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  background-color: #f44336;
}

/* Center the image and position the close button */
.imgcontainer {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
  position: relative;
}

img.avatar {
  width: 30%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.container {
  padding: 16px;
}

span.psw {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
  padding-top: 60px;
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 5% auto 15% auto; /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and centered */
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button (x) */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 10px;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.bt-cloae {
  border: none;
}
.buttons {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
table {
  text-align: center;
}

/* Add Zoom Animation */
.animate {
  -webkit-animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
  animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatezoom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes animatezoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

/* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  span.psw {
    display: block;
    float: none;
  }
  .cancelbtn {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
</style>
```

Please help me to fix this problem.